# asp.net select row in grid set

Tags: asp.net

I have a gridview that I want to read, delete, edit and update, I have all the methods set up correctly. I need to know how to enable the grid view so I can select a row to then invoke the delete. Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsumeDSetService
{
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public static DataSet ds;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        localhost.Service1 myws = new localhost.Service1();
        ds = myws.GetDataSet();
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //updates database in web service with contents of dataset
        localhost.Service1 myws = new localhost.Service1();
        Label7.Text = myws.ModifyDatabase(ds);
    }

    protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //reads student record after row in grid view has been selected
        int i = GridView1.SelectedIndex;
        TextBox1.Text = System.Convert.ToString(ds.Tables["Students"].Rows[i]["RollNumber"]);
        TextBox2.Text = System.Convert.ToString(ds.Tables["Students"].Rows[i]["FirstName"]);
        TextBox3.Text = System.Convert.ToString(ds.Tables["Students"].Rows[i]["Surname"]);
        TextBox4.Text = System.Convert.ToString(ds.Tables["Students"].Rows[i]["Course"]);
        TextBox5.Text = System.Convert.ToString(ds.Tables["Students"].Rows[i]["Level"]);
        TextBox6.Text = System.Convert.ToString(ds.Tables["Students"].Rows[i]["Address"]);
    }

    protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //inserts new row into database
        DataRow dr = ds.Tables["Students"].NewRow();
        dr["RollNumber"] = TextBox1.Text;
        dr["FirstName"] = TextBox2.Text;
        dr["Surname"] = TextBox3.Text;
        dr["Course"] = TextBox4.Text;
        dr["Level"] = TextBox5.Text;
        dr["Address"] = TextBox6.Text;
        ds.Tables["Students"].Rows.Add(dr);
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void Button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //edits data row in set
        int i = GridView1.SelectedIndex;
        ds.Tables["Students"].Rows[i]["RollNumber"] = TextBox1.Text;
        ds.Tables["Students"].Rows[i]["FirstName"] = TextBox2.Text;
        ds.Tables["Students"].Rows[i]["Surname"] = TextBox3.Text;
        ds.Tables["Students"].Rows[i]["Course"] = TextBox4.Text;
        ds.Tables["Students"].Rows[i]["Level"] = TextBox5.Text;
        ds.Tables["Students"].Rows[i]["Address"] = TextBox6.Text;
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void Button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //deletes row in set
        int i = GridView1.SelectedIndex;
        ds.Tables["Students"].Rows[i].Delete();
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The `GridView` control has built-in events for handling editing, updating, and deleting. It looks to me like you're sort of re-inventing those handlers outside of the `GridView`. My suggestion would be to set up the appropriate event handlers for the `GridView`'s `OnRowEditing`, `OnRowCancelEdit`, `OnRowUpdating`, and `OnRowDeleting` events. There are countless examples of this on the Internet -- I'll leave [most of] the research as an exercise for you, but [here's an example](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article29.aspx) anyway.

Comment: Should the row be selected on click, or do you have a select button in each row?

Comment: @James Johnson either way is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select a row onclick, you can use something like this:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(Me.GridView1, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex.ToString()))
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks, seems I can also use the edit columns and add a select button.

Comment: Yes, that's another approach. The GridView has most of the commonly needed functionality built-in.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are in wrong direction. Not sure how you going to obtain the `selectedIndex` of the `gridview` in a separate `buttonclick` event.

To get an idea to how to perform insert, update and delete in a grid-view, have a look at these article about

[GridView Examples for ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972948.aspx)

[Insert, Update, Delete with Gridview....simple way](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24085/Insert-Update-Delete-with-Gridview-simple-way)

[How to use GridView with Insert, Edit, Update, Delete the Ado.net way C#](http://howtouseasp.net/how-to-use-gridview-with-insert-edit-update-delete-the-ado-net-way-c/)

Hope this might direct you in correct direction